# Which Harry Potter Characters Appear in All Seven Books Only to Die In Book Seven?

Tags: harry-potter

**Which *Harry Potter* characters appear in all seven books, only to die in book seven? [MAJOR SPOILERS/CHARACTER DEATHS]**

I can go either way on

> Harry,

depending on your interpretation of the *King's Cross* chapter in *Deathly Hallows*.

> Some feel he died; other believe it was more along the lines of a near-death experience. I'll accept either interpretation.

- I'm not requesting this, but just as an FYI: It's fun to try and
  answer questions like this from memory before hitting up canon.
- This is not a list question, as there is a finite number of
  characters who fit the question's criteria.

★ I'm looking for a canon-based answer (the seven *Harry Potter* novels, the three supplemental books, J.K. Rowling interviews, and Pottermore) and do not prefer an answer from either the HP Wikia or the Wikipedia.

<sub>NOTE: A few months ago I got an email from a fellow SFF.se user about the *Harry Potter* questions on the site. Now, I cannot find her email :/ She asked me this question as a personal challenge and I put it onto the back burner, but today I decided I would post it here and see if the user who emailed me will comment so I can fully credit her for the question.</sub>

Comment: Do **mentions** of a character count? (e.g. Tom Riddle/Voldemort in HP3, or Peter/Scabbers in HP5)

Comment: Also, do you want actual book quotes proving each character appeared in all 7 books?

Comment: @DVK -- No, offhanded mentions shouldn't count, I don't think. The character has to have been actively part of the story. No, I don't think book quotes are necessary. And, yes, the deaths of the characters are of great interest in *Harry Potter* and enjoy having outlines like this. :)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

#### Yes 100%:

- **Fred Weasley**
- **Hedwig**
- **Severus Snape**
- **Vincent Crabbe**

#### Yes if you count being *mentioned* in a book without being an active character:

- **Peter Pettigrew**
  Appeared first as Scabbers, only got a flashback in HP5.
- **Tom Riddle aka Lord Voldemort**
  This one is a bit iffy, as he did not appear as an acting character in HP3, and only appeared as a Horcrux/Tom in HP2.

---

#### Maybe (You can lawyer that they did appear, were implied, or whether they died):

- **Harry Potter** (duh)
  It's disputed whether he died in DH in the first place.
- **Lavender Brown**
  She clearly died in the movie but not 100% clear if she was
  merely severely injured in the book. All we get is:

  > “NO!” shrieked Hermione, and with a deafening blast from her
  > wand, Fenrir Greyback was thrown backward
  > from the feebly struggling body of Lavender Brown.

  We know that JKR had a fairly big input into the movies, so presumably she was on board with a major items like who among recurring characters died.
- **Bloody Baron** (As Slytherin Ghost) [ Did not appear in HP3 ]
- **Helena Ravenclaw** (as Ravenclaw Ghost) [ Did not appear in HP3/HP4 ]
  Both ghosts didn't actually die in Year 7,
  ... but their death was first described in Deathly Hallows.
  Also, they weren't mentioned in 1 or 2 books explicitly,
  ... but it's assumed they still were house ghosts in Years 3 and 4.
- **Bathilda Bagshot** (as author of "History of Magic" textbook).
  The class wasn't even mentioned in HP6
  ... but presumably taught
  and the textbook wasn't named after HP1,
  ... but presumed to be used in all years (no canon yea/nay).

---

#### Runner-ups:

- **Colin Creevey**
  First appeared in HP2, was in every book since.

Comment: Add some of the reanimated suits of armors to the “maybe” list, as those suits have been in Hogwarts for ages, and it's likely that some of them were destroyed in the battle.

Comment: Nice list! In the books, it is not established that Lavender Brown died, although she did in the movie *DH2*. Hmm, Scabbers? I'd like to know what other people think too, but I lean towards no because he was unidentified until the end of *PoA*, but also yes because Peter Pettigrew was indeed Scabbers the rat. Thoughts?

Comment: I vote yes on the Peter Pettigrew/Scabbers issue.  I mean, when it was finally revealed in HP3 that Scabbers was Pettigrew, I surely wasn't the only one who was like, "So that's why she keeps going on and on about Ron's stupid rat!".  I think it was clearly JK's intent to establish his presence prior to PoA.  And, btw, I was most upset about the death of Colin Creevey.  I feel like he should be included honorarily.  Bless his heart.

Comment: Agreed about Colin.

Comment: @Slytherincess - an Animagus animal form fully retains the mind of the wizard, so Scabbers counts AFAIAC. I put extra details for Lavender. Since the movies were presumably OKed by JKR in major details like this,  I'm inclined to keep her, but in the Maybe column.

Comment: Also, Peter was mentioned by Stan Shunpike on the Knight Bus as 'a wizard': "...and Black took out his wand, and he blasted half the street apart! And a wizard got it, and so did a dozen muggles..."

Comment: Flitwick? Didn't he die in 7?

Comment: @Yamikuronue - no

Answer (score 12):

I was the one who proposed the trivia question to Slytherincess.  The exact wording of the question is:

What characters appeared ALIVE in each of the seven books, but at the end of the seventh book are dead?  This wording would exclude ghosts, mentions (anecdotes told by other characters), and appearances in photos/portraits (not alive).

My answers are:

Snape
Crabbe
Fred Weasley
Hedwig the Owl

I considered Lavender Brown, but it wasn't explicitly stated that she died (in the book).  Peter Pettigrew/Scabbers didn't appear "alive" in book 5.

Comment: Welcome to the site! While it's appreciated that you provided the question, **your answer seems to be identical to mine except with less details** - your list is basically the same as my "Yes" list with 2 characters removed who explicitly were noted as not being "alive" in all 7 books despite being listed as "yes" due to Slytherincess slightly ambiguous wording.