# What happened to Lavender Brown?

Tags: harry-potter

I have not yet finished the books, but I have seen the films, and in the final film, I think I saw the trio run past Lavender in the courtyard as someone drank her blood.  Is this correct?

DVK's answer to **[this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/25244/which-harry-potter-characters-appear-in-all-seven-books-only-to-die-in-book-seve) states that she died, but what actually happened to Lavender? Is it different in the books?**

Comment: It was her, and it was Fenrir Greyback attacking her rather than drinking her blood (werewolf). That's just the films though, been a while so can't vouch for books :)

Comment: I disagree with the dupe. That other question asks about deaths in general, and lists Lavender Brown as "possibly", while this question asks about her specifically and in depth.

Answer (score 35):

In the book, Lavender's death isn't explicitly confirmed, nor have there been any statements from JKR confirming her fate. For several months (until December 2015) her "*Fact-File*" on the new Pottermore site [originally stated](http://web.archive.org/web/20150922164556/https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/lavender-brown) that she was "**Presumed Dead, 2 May 1998**" however this has been amended to remove that statement (without explanation).

In the film, the scene where she's killed is much more definitive and there have been follow-up interviews that absolutely confirm her death at the hands of the werewolf, Fenrir Greyback

---

### Book Canon

In the final Potter book, Lavender's last mention is that she was "feebly stirring" (see below) however her injuries seem extremely severe, she isn't mentioned again, she isn't on Platform 9¾ in the final chapter, nor does she appear as a character in Harry Potter and the Cursed Child.

> *Harry, Ron and Hermione sped down the marble staircase: glass
>   shattered to their left and the Slytherin hourglass that had recorded
>   house points spilled its emeralds everywhere, so that people slipped
>   and staggered as they ran. Two bodies fell from the balcony overhead
>   as they reached the ground and a grey blur that Harry took for an
>   animal sped four-legged across the hall to sink its teeth into one of
>   the fallen.*
>
> *‘NO!’ shrieked Hermione, and with a deafening blast from her wand
>   Fenrir Greyback was thrown backwards from the feebly stirring body of
>   Lavender Brown. He hit the marble banisters and struggled to return to
>   his feet. Then, with a bright white flash and a crack, a crystal ball
>   fell on the top of his head and he crumpled to the ground and did not
>   move.*

---

### Movie Canon

In [an interview](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2011/12/02/uk-dvd-launch-event-report-and-interview-transcript/) to launch the UK DVD, the actress who played Lavender Brown (Jessie Cave) stated that we do indeed see her character die at the end of Deathly Hallows Pt II.

> **Q :** *What was the last scene you filmed on the very last film?*
>
> **Jessie Cave :** ***Mine was my death scene***. Which is quite fitting, really.

This is also confirmed in the tie-in book [Harry Potter Page to Screen: The Complete Filmmaking Journey](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_Page_to_Screen:_The_Complete_Filmmaking_Journey)

> Jessie Cave was also happy to come back, even knowing that Lavender
>   Brown wasn't going to survive the final film. "*She's not very lucky,*"
>   the actress understates. **"*She doesn't meet a nice ending. She gets
>   eaten by Fenrir Greyback.*"**
>
> **Cave recalls her death scene,** which took several nights of shooting.
>   "*I had the most amazing prosthetic of a scar that looked so scary, it
>   looked like I was actually mauled to death.*"

Comment: I'd say, though it's a pure speculation, the fact that Hermione was the one to protect Lavender (ex-girlfriend of her love, you know) is a significant detail, so it would make total sense in terms of the story that she was the one who actually **saved** her. If she just jinxes Grayback and Lavender still dies - her actions doesn't seem so meaningful anymore (again, just in terms of the storytelling)

Comment: “there have been follow-up interviews that absolutely confirm her death at the hands of the werewolf, Fenrir Greyback”. Do you have links or quotes for these?

Comment: @Thunderforge - One is already linked above. If memory serves I found another that had essentially the same talking points which is why I didn't bother adding it

Answer (score 5):

Note that on Lavender's fact file on Pottermore (currently found [here](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/lavender-brown)), no date of death is mentioned. Compare to Crabbe, Colin, Tonks, Lupin, and Fred, for example, who all include the death date of May 2, 1998.

Comment: Interestingly, it used to say "***DEATH: Presumed dead, 2 May 1998***". That notification has been removed. No information exists to explain why that change was made; http://web.archive.org/web/20150922164556/https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/lavender-brown

Answer (score 0):

She is dead because there is an article:(https://www.bustle.com/articles/53943-j-k-rowling-apologizes-for-this-harry-potter-characters-death-but-she-needs-to-apologize-s article basically says that she is sorry for killing off people in the Harry Potter series and Lavender Brown is one of them.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should include a relevant quote from the article in your answer in case the link disappears some day.