# How many children in Harry's year die?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

During the battle of Hogwarts, in Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, we learn that Lavender Brown ends up dying.

However, it's been a while since I read the books, so, I was wondering, of the 40 children in Harry's year, who else dies, and how?

Comment: Actually whether or not Lavender Brown died is debatable. I personally think she didn't https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72611/what-happened-to-lavender-brown

Comment: Also judging by the linked question in that post, the answer to your question is 1 or 2: Crabbe and maybe Lavender https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/25244/which-harry-potter-characters-appear-in-all-seven-books-only-to-die-in-book-seve

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/128936/4918 "Who died in Harry Potter?"

Comment: Eventually, all of them.  Don't yet know how.

Comment: Lol. Clever. :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### At least one, (but possibly up to thirty-four)

The only confirmed death in Harry's year was Vincent Crabbe.

> Malfoy fell off the broom and lay facedown, gasping, coughing, and retching. Harry rolled over and sat up: The door to the Room of Requirement had vanished, and Ron and Hermione sat panting on the floor beside Goyle, who was still unconscious.
>
> “C-Crabbe,” choked Malfoy as soon as he could speak. “CCrabbe . . .”
>
> “He’s dead,” said Ron harshly.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - Chapter Thirty One</sub>

There is some speculation that Lavender Brown died as well, but it's far from conclusive.

To the best of my knowledge, the only characters from Harry's year that Rowling has confirmed to have survived the battle are Harry, Ron, Hermione, Neville, Hannah, and Draco. The other thirty-four *may* have died.

---

<sub>As the Dark Lord would like to point out, Harry technically died as well, (but seeing as this was only temporary, I decided not to count it.)</sub>

Comment: Lavender Brown most probably didn't actually die because Fenrir Greyback had only turned her a werewolf because he is one. So technically, Lavender Brown didn't die, she only got turned into a werewolf.

Comment: Are you sure there's nobody else from Harry's year who appears on the platform in the epilogue?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - JKR wrote the epilogue before most of the characters were developed. Besides for a few minor edits she made later (e.g. Teddy), only the core book one characters are even mentioned. (Hannah is only known from 2007 interviews and the 2014 QWC writings.)

Comment: Technically, Harry died as well.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - Your one high point of the battle. Shame that it didn't last so long.